# Adding thumbnail attribute in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, image

I'm trying to apply a jQuery plugin on my wordpress site called Adaptive Backgrounds http://briangonzalez.github.io/jquery.adaptive-backgrounds.js/.

I want to use it for my post thumbnails. The readme documentation says:

> The script looks for image(s) with the `data-adaptive-background`
>   attribute:
>
> `html <img src="/image.jpg" data-adaptive-background='1'>`

My question is: How do I add this attribute to my post thumbnails, and my post thumbnails only?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, just change “large” to whatever your thumbnail is called.

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'large', array( 'data-adaptive-background' => 1 ) );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail